# Youtube-API Related Channels to a Channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way I can get a list of channels that are related to a particular youtube channel. Like we have on the youtube page? I know there is an api to get videos related to a video but how do I do it for a channel. The following website seems to be doing it:

http://vidooly.com/channel/UCbTLwN10NoCU4WDzLf1JMOA#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially there is no way to get the channels related to a channel using the youtube API. It can only return the featured channels shown on a Youtube Channel page.

So I am closing this for now.